# C# to MySqlDB update

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm currently working on a little example for a friend to record employers working time. Therefore I want to update the record of a MySQL database.

The connection to the DB is already done and is working on the test, however, I do not manage (and yes I googled a lot) to actually get the values changing in the DB. This is my current attempt to give out the current time for when employers start working:

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    // Die Verbindung zur DB entnehmen.
    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        // Der Befehl UPDATE.
        string sql = "UPDATE user SET lastlogin = lastlogin WHERE user username = srademacher";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        MySqlParameter lastlogin = new MySqlParameter("@lastlogin", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        lastlogin.Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(lastlogin);

        // Command durchführen
        int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        conn = null;
    }

    Console.Read();
    MessageBox.Show("Die Arbeit wurde um " + DateTime.Now + " aufgenommen");
}
```

I guess you could call me a noob at scripting but I would be happy to get some advice to become better :-) thank you for your ideas.

Edit: I do not have any problems launching the application the code accords to, just the DateTime Value in DB does not change

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement has incorrect syntax, `WHERE user username = srademacher`. Then you add `MySqlParameter` but not using that in sql.

Change `sql` to

```
string sql = "UPDATE user SET lastlogin = @lastlogin WHERE username = @username";
```

and  add

```
 MySqlParameter username = new MySqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
 username.Value = "srademacher";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(username);
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your quick answer, if i understand right that should be immpüossible as we trie to export a username right now to a filed that is allowed to be filled with datetime or did i get that wrong ?

Tried it anyways, with no change as result ( also exchanged .DateTime for VarChar in username parameter

Comment: Of course you can hardcoded username. Then use `string sql = "UPDATE user SET lastlogin = @lastlogin WHERE username = \"srademacher\"";`

Comment: yeah, the hardcoded was more like an placeholder to get everything funktioning first and thn care about specifications. i think it might just not find the table to write in.. but thanks for that part anyways, safed me some time :P